# .htaccess Rewrite Regular Expression Issue

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried debugging this with various regex testers on the web but they all seem to indicate that the syntax is correct, not to mention, this expression worked when I was using it in a `web.config` file.

However, I am currently in the process of moving my web application over to a new Linux Server, and apparently, my `.htaccess` returns a `500 Internal Server Error` when this particular rewrite is enabled:

```
# Set the General Page Rewrite
RewriteRule ^([^(?!_)\/]+)\/?([^(?!_)\/]+)?\/?([^\/]+)?\/?$ $1.php?request=$2&id=$3& [NC,QSA,L]
```

Can anyone see where the regex is failing?

### Update

This is the error in my log:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace

Comment: Prepend second (destination) part with `/` (right before `$1`)

Comment: @AndrewDunai Don't quite understand... Do you mean put  `/$1.php...`??? If so, that definitely isn't the issue I'm afraid :-(

Comment: Yes. This may be the reason.

Comment: Ah, also, do you have `RewriteEngine On` before the rules? And is `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: @AndrewDunai Afraid not. I tested it out of courtesy but I knew it wasnt going to be the issue unfortunately as I have around 10 other rewrites in the same `.htaccess` and none of them have it...

Comment: So other rewrites in the same `.htaccess` work?

Comment: @AndrewDunai Of course :-). I am 100% sure the issue is in the regex... There are many other rewrites running in the .htaccess, adn they work fine if I comment this line out

Comment: @AndrewDunai Whilst even the most experienced programmers can miss the smallest of errors, I have thoroughly tested this file, and debugged as far as my regex skills will take me, hence, I am now asking on SO. The issue is with this particular rule, nothing else in the file :-)

Comment: Damn, this is really strange :) I could reproduce this as well.

Comment: Do you have access to the server’s error log?

Comment: @CBroe Of course, give me a sec :-)

Comment: Looks like what you are rewriting to is caught by the rule again on next iteration … enable rewrite logging to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: @CBroe How do I access the rewrite logs?